# Supporting WKT "PROJCRS[...]"

Tags: java, geotools

Currently my Java application uses CRS parser to convert a WKT to a Co-ordinate Reference System.  This works fine for "PROJCS[...]" However after some off the shelf tools generates "PROJCRS[...]" the solutions fails to parse.

```
        String wkt = "PROJCRS[...]" // (Some WKT 2.0 string)
        org.geotools.referencing.CRS.parseWKT(wkt);
```

My question relates to when/if we should expect support for later versions of WKT through geo-tools

As this is expected I have tried a number of other libraries (to varying success) including

- Apache SIS
- GDAL

My goal with this question is to weigh up bringing more dependencies to the solution vs expectation of new geo-tools versions.  I am reaching out here because my understanding is this represents geo-tools supporting WKT 2.0 and that this would be a broad effort by the geo-tools community

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be conflating two different types of well known text - projections and geometries (ISO-19107) - that are totally unrelated.

However, looking at the [spec](https://docs.ogc.org/is/18-010r7/18-010r7.html#71) and the [code](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/f0556d450f0ade2e7e98e6f1e94c95e2c57f5660/modules/library/referencing/src/main/java/org/geotools/referencing/wkt/Parser.java#L229) there does seem to be a missing prefix (`PROJCRS`). So I would raise an issue and submit a PR with the fix and a test case.

Comment: I appreciate how I have conflated Geometry and Projection.

Regarding your feedback to jump in and contribute to an open source project.  There is a possibility this is on the cards.  My understanding of what I am requesting is WKT 2.0 support where geo-tools currently supports WKT 1.0.  I imagined giving a major version change this would be something the geo-tools community would be actively working towards.

Comment: As far as I can see it is in WKT 1.0 but obviously no one is using it or someone would have noticed before now. Apparently: "Projected CRS is defined in Clause 9.In this International Standard the following definitions from ISO 19125‑1:2004 and OGC 01-009 have been deprecated but are included here for the purposes of documenting backward compatibility."